# How to set jquery unbind as toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, unbind

Following is my script to show and hide content on click of a div.
I also want to disable other div elements until the first div is clicked again.

```
$('.leader-pic-wrapper').click(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var bottom = $el.position().top + ($el.outerHeight(true) - 30);
    $('.leader-pic-overlay').toggle();
    $('.leader-pic-wrapper').not(this).toggleClass('inactive-leader');

    /*$(".inactive-leader").unbind("click");*/
    $(".inactive-leader").off("click");

    $(this).next('.leader-profile-wrapper').css('top', bottom);
    $(this).next('.leader-profile-wrapper').toggle();
});
```

I don't understand how to toggle the unbind statement. I tried toggling a class called inactive-leader and apply unbind to that class, but its not working.

Basically I want to set unbind on

```
leader-pic-wrapper
```

Thanks

Comment: which version are you using ? maybe move to use **on() & off()**

Comment: just tried off - it works..but the question still remains, how to I make it on on second click on the same element...

Comment: Instead of binding or unbinding i'd use a var that keeps track of the status, and only one initial binding, and update this var (or array of statuses vars if needed more than one) and check in the function the status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My option is approach this with a different view. Without bind and unbind the event just exclude the items with the first selector using `:not()`, and as you are doing add a class to the elements you want to exclude; please check this snippet:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.box:not(".disabled")', function() {
  if ($('.disabled').length) {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('disabled')
    $(this).animate({
      'width': '80px'
    }, 300)
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().addClass('disabled')
    $(this).animate({
      'width': '160px'
    }, 300)
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

This logic on your code will look like this:

```
//Delegate the event since we are add/remove the class
//Target the elements that aren't inactive
$('body').on('click', '.leader-pic-wrapper:not(".inactive-leader")', function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var bottom = $el.position().top + ($el.outerHeight(true) - 30);

  //Check if exists some inactive elements to handle 1/2 click
  if ($('.inactive-leader').length) {
    //Target other leader-pic-wrapper elements, use sibling or the method you need based on your markup
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('inactive-leader')
    //...ACTIONS - This will act as the second click
  } else {
    $(this).siblings().addClass('inactive-leader')
    //...ACTIONS - This will act as the first click
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly...I'll need to read a bit of documentation before I can fully understand this.

Comment: glad to help U @StacyJ if you have any question about this lines of code I'll be very happy to solve it

Comment: hey, i need to add a close button inside a div outside .box element. This div opens when I click on the .box and has a close button. I wrote an extra block of code - on click of close button close the div and remove inactive-leader class. This works fine except, after I close using the close button, .box needs 2 clicks to work the usual way. Any idea why it happens

Comment: @StacyJ can you elaborate an example on codepen or jsfiddle to see theissue ?

Comment: the script works perfectly on desktop but not on ipad and iphone. Any idea why this would happen. I added touch event with click, but then the entire script stops working